# Gtk widget pointer comparision

Tags: gtk, widget

i want to compare two Gtk widget pointer values for equality. how can i do it?
  not able to do with normal equality(==) or typecasting it to int...

```
GtkWidget *a;
GtkWidget *b;

if((int)a == (int)b)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A pointer is a pointer. If `a` points to a widget, and `b` points to the same widget, then you can test using `if (a == b)`.